# Getting undefined error in mass text app

Tags: ruby, json, irb

I'm creating a app that sends mass texts using a JSON file with the numbers and names. Every time I test load the app in IRB I get the error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `data_from_file' for main:Object
        from /home/qc/tep/Coding Stuff/Ruby/text app/main.rb:14:in `contacts_from_file'
```

I understand what the error means, but I don't understand why I'm getting the error, here's the source code:

```
require 'json'

def sanatize(numbers)
    "+1" + number.gsub(/^1|\D/, "")
end

def numbers_from_file
    file = open('numbers.json').read
    JSON.parse(file)
end

def contacts_from_file
    contacts= { }
    data_from_file['feed']['entry'].each do |entry|
        name = entry['gsx$name']['$t']
        number = entry['gsx$number']['$t']
        contacts[sanatize(number)] = name
    end
    contacts
end

def contact_numbers
    contacts_from_file.keys
end

def contact_name
    contacts_from_file[number]
end
```

And here's the JSON file:

```
{ 
    '1**********' => 'Big Bird'
    '1**********'} => 'Josh'
}
```

If anybody could help me and tell me why the `data_from_file` is "undefined" it would be extremely helpful, thank you ahead of time.

Comment: "and tell me why the data_from_file is undefined" - well, because you didn't define it, that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never define `data_from_file`, you just try to read from it in the `contects_from_file` method.

Perhaps you meant `numbers_from_file` instead of `data_from_file`?